# Getting the status of a file in CVS without checking it out

Tags: command-line, version-control, cvs, wincvs

Is this possible?  Running the status command on a path that exists in the repository but is not checked out locally results in the following error:

**Command:**

`cvs status dir`

**Output:**

> cvs status: Examining "dir"
>
> cvs [status aborted]: could not chdir to "dir": No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the wrong command - what is it you want to do?

Status gives you the current status of a checked out file, so it by definition requires a sandbox with the file checked out in order to compare that to your repository.

You might be looking for the rlog command.  It will output information about the file without having a checked out copy - it is the "remote" version of the log command (thus "rlog").

This command will give you the default information about the file "hi.doc" located within the "samp" module:

```
cvs rlog samp/hi.doc
```

Or, if you don't have your CVSROOT environment variable set, use this instead:

```
cvs -d CVSROOT rlog samp/hi.doc
```

Does that help?